# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 communicating with Arduino using Bluetooth

Tags: c#, silverlight, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I connected the Windows Phone 8 with arudino using bluetooth as given in sample here

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_communicating_with_Arduino_using_Bluetooth#Complete_example

This is working okay for Windows Phone 8 but when i retarget the app to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, i am getting Debugger.Break and on continue,i get  exception "exception has been thrown by target of invocation".

I used code:

```
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
        var pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

        if (pairedDevices.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No paired devices were found.");
        }
        else
        { 
            foreach (var pairedDevice in pairedDevices)
            {
                if (pairedDevice.DisplayName == DeviceName.Text)
                {
                    connectionManager.Connect(pairedDevice.HostName);
                    ConnectAppToDeviceButton.Content = "Connected";
                    DeviceName.IsReadOnly = true;
                    ConnectAppToDeviceButton.IsEnabled = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Where connect function is defined as:

```
public async void Connect(HostName deviceHostName)
    {
        if (socket != null)
        {
            await socket.ConnectAsync(deviceHostName, "1");
            dataReader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
            dataReadWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            dataWriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        }
    }
```

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried working with the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm namespace? It's pretty much made for Windows 8.1 bluetooth communication.

[Setting device capabilities.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263090.aspx)

```
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
  <m2:Device Id="any">
    <m2:Function Type="serviceId:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"/>
  </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability>
```

Selecting Device: This is where you have to parse the Guid of the device you are using. Afterwards you use the parsed Guid to find every device that offers that service. (I used the SerialPort Guid)

```
Guid RfcommChatServiceUuid = Guid.Parse("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(RfcommChatServiceUuid)));
```

Connecting: DeviceInformation returns a list of DeviceInformation. With a chatserviceInfo.Id you can create a new RfcommDeviceService. (In this case it's called "service")

```
StreamSocket _socket;    
RfcommDeviceService service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(chatserviceInfo1._id);
await _socket.ConnectAsync(service.ConnectionHostName, service.ConnectionServiceName);
```

Disconnecting:

```
this._socket.Dispose();
this._socket = null;
```

Comment: I set the device capabilities.I have still few question? can we put service id randomly? If not how to know service id? Also what is _id and ConnectionServiceName?

Comment: Seems I made a small mistake, let's change it up!

Comment: again what is chatserviceInfo1._id and how to get it? Also should we declare service as var?

Comment: 1. DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync returns a list of ChatServiceInfo. ChatserviceInfo1 is just a placeholder for one of values of that list, the service you decide to connect to.

2. You can declare it like how I did it in the exampe, var is also fine.

Comment: sorry for the ignorance but i don't know how to take values from DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync..if i put just chatserviceInfo1._id, it gives error it doesn't exist.

Comment: If you just have 1 bluetooth device paired you can use;
DeviceInformation chatserviceInfo1 = devices.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Otherwise you can just enumerate through the list and find the device you want.